# How to disable delete action on UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableViewCell where I have implemented `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath` to allow users to drag right on cells to add them to their favorites. However, in doing so the option for dragging left to delete also appeared. I don't want these cells to be able to be deleted. Is there a way to implement swipe actions without the delete action appearing?

Comment: U need leadingSwipe alone? or leadingSwipe and trailingSwipe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Edit

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

   let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [])
   swipeAction.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false // This is the line which disables full swipe
   return swipeAction
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but please see my edit for clarification. It's not that I want to add delete actions to some cells, I want no delete actions on any cells.

Comment: I still want to be able to add my own actions though. I just don't want the default delete one

Comment: in leading Swipe you can configue title and image

Comment: I have already done that. That gives me the leading action I want but it also adds a trailing delete that I do not want.